# Symfony 2 attachment response file name

Tags: symfony, response

I have this code:

```
        $response = $excelService->getResponse(); // create response for excel object bundle
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.basename('filename.xls'));
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
        $response->sendHeaders();
        return $response;
```

And when I click to download this file to my disk it's name is: *filename.xls, attachment*
how can I remove this '*attachment*' from my file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `$response->sendHeaders();`